# Android - How to keep android from re-sizing bitmap images

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, textures

For the past two days Ive been struggling with texture issues in opengl where the textures just come up as white boxes on certain devices and on everything else they show up fine. Ive double checked and used only POT (power of two) images and that did not resolve the problem. From what I read Im thinking that android is doing something to the bitmaps on these certain devices that is knocking them out of dimension and then causing the textures to come up blank or white.

These images that I am using are not stored within the apk although I have tried to use images stored in the local resources and it doesnt seem to make a difference whether their stored locally or Im using images streamed to the device in the form of a stream. My only other guess is that I need to do something to keep certain builds of android from resizing the images but I dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For bitmaps stored as resources with your apk, you can prevent the system from scaling them by putting them in folder `res/drawable-nodpi`. For images created from a stream, the system normally assumes that they are intended for a medium density (160dpi) display and will scale accordingly. You can prevent this through various api calls as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#scaling).

The recommended approach is to provide separate graphics resources for each screen resolution supported. The basic technique is described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support).

Comment: Hey thanks for the links :) I looked over lots of material in the android docs but never came across that before.

Comment: Success!!!! For now anyway until my app goes live and some other device beside the ones in my test group give me more unseen errors :p But I finally got some local resources drawing as textures on my objects in opengl on the certain devices

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using 9patch images, If you patch them properly, Android will not scale the images

Comment: No Ive never tried messing with 9patches however I think I read somewhere that the android system will ignore certain flags when using them. Not sure if that would be bad or good for my use but have you used them when using opengl?